# how to add a basic input discount on javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the code i want to create this form were you input all the information like price, quantity and %discount and have the discount amount shown the subtotal and the total 
as the discount amount being the %discount divided by 100 and then multiplied by the subtotal. The subtotal is made by multiplying the price by quantity. And the total is made by multiplying the subtotal by discount as you can see i have the form complete and i have almost all the code on the javascript but it seems i cant make it work with the discount. Please help !

JS:

```
$('#CAT_Custom_490527').keyup(function () {
    var quantity = $("#CAT_Custom_490527").val();
    var iPrice = $("#CAT_Custom_490526").val();
    var subtotal = quantity * iPrice;
    $("#CAT_Custom_491101").val(subtotal);
    var x = $("#CAT_Custom_491074").val();
    var y = 100
    var division = x / y
    var multi = division * subtotal
    $("CAT_Custom_491074").val(division);
    var total = subtotal * multi;
    $("#CAT_Custom_490531").val(total);
    // sets the total price input to the quantity * price
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="CAT_Custom_490526">Precio <span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="CAT_Custom_490526" id="CAT_Custom_490526" class="cat_textbox" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="CAT_Custom_490527">Cantidad <span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="CAT_Custom_490527" id="CAT_Custom_490527" class="cat_textbox" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="CAT_Custom_491074">%Descuento</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="CAT_Custom_491074" id="CAT_Custom_491074" class="cat_textbox" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="CAT_Custom_491218">Descuento</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="CAT_Custom_491218" id="CAT_Custom_491218" class="cat_textbox" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="CAT_Custom_491101">Subtotal</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="CAT_Custom_491101" id="CAT_Custom_491101" class="cat_textbox" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="CAT_Custom_490531">Total <span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="CAT_Custom_490531" id="CAT_Custom_490531" class="cat_textbox" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: When you say "cant make it work," what do you mean? What is happening instead of what's expected?

Comment: when you type the price and quantity the subtotal shows, but when you type the %discount the discount amount doesnt show nor the total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble spots I see:

1. Incorrect Math (thanks to [answer by krb686](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17174018/361684) - please upvote that answer since it is helpful)
2. Typo in selector - missing `#` (thanks to [answer by Kundan Singh Chouhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17173941/361684) - please upvote that answer since it is helpful)
3. After correcting the typo above, you are now overwriting the discount percent.  I bet you meant that to be used for the discount value field: `#CAT_Custom_491218`.  This would be much easier to detect ahead of time if you use meaningful ids instead of auto-generated ids.
4. You are only evaluating this function when the quantity field is changed.  If you change, for example, the discount percent, the subtotal and total are not re-evaluated.
5. You are only watching keyboard events.  If the value was changed using the mouse only (copy/paste or drag/drop), the subtotal and total are not re-evaluated.  Also handle `oninput` (a new event for html5) and `onchange`.

To bind to all of the inputs and detect more events than just `keyup`:

```
$("input").on("input keyup change", function () {
    ...
```

[Demo with all the above changes applied](http://jsfiddle.net/963Wg/)

Comment: WOW !! Thank you very much ! i was breaking my head with that i had a week trying to figure this out. you just saved my life thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You missed the "#" form your textbox ID, it should be

```
$("#CAT_Custom_491074").val(division);
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: i already fixed that small typo and it didn't fixed the issue. when you type the price and quantity the subtotal shows, but when you type the %discount the discount amount doesnt show nor the total

Answer (score 0):

**Your math is incorrect**

So if I enter 50 in the discount box, x = 50, y = 100,

1. `division = x/y` = `50/100` = `0.5`
2. Say subtotal = $100, then `multi = subtotal * division` = `$100 * 0.5` = `$50`
3. Then, `total = subtotal * multi` = `$100 * $50` = `$5000`

You shouldn't be multiplying subtotal * multi.

Why don't you just do:

```
total = subtotal * (1 - discount/100)
```

Essentially (1 - discount/100) is your multiplier.  If I enter 12 for discount, it becomes:

`total = ($100) * (1 - 12/100)`, or `($100) * 0.88`, or `$88`

**Or**

Just change your last line of code to:

```
total = subtotal - multi
```

multi isn't holding a multiplier, it's holding the amount you want to take off the total.